# Why my JSON values are getting duplicated in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

Here is my BeanShell script which I wrote in JMeter

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0;i<=3;i++)
{   

    JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
    innerObject.put("middleName", "${__RandomString(4,KLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ,)}");
    innerObject.put("maidenName", "${__RandomString(4,HUDNSERTFG,)}");
    innerObject.put("gender", "${__RandomString(1,MFU,)}");
    innerObject.put("TestingType", "${__RandomString(1,IE,)}");
    jsonArray.put(innerObject);
    outerObject.put("nameList", jsonArray);
    
}
    
    outerObject.put("Alert", "Testing Alert");
    
    log.info(outerObject.toString());
    vars.putObject("jsonData",jsonArray);
```

Here is the JSON response which I am getting

```
{
  "nameList": [
    {
      "gender": "M",
      "maidenName": "DUDT",
      "middleName": "ZPMZ",
      "TestingType": "E"
    },
   {
      "gender": "M",
      "maidenName": "DUDT",
      "middleName": "ZPMZ",
      "TestingType": "E"
    },
    {
      "gender": "M",
      "maidenName": "DUDT",
      "middleName": "ZPMZ",
      "TestingType": "E"
    },
    {
      "gender": "M",
      "maidenName": "DUDT",
      "middleName": "ZPMZ",
      "TestingType": "E"
    }
  ],
  "Alert": "Testing Alert"
}
```

[image] [image]

As you can see the JSON above, all the values are duplicated. I want to have different values for all the variable. Am I missing anything? Please guide me if anything wrong with my code. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the JMeter element configuration ?

Comment: Hi, I have added the screenshot for the same. Please let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using JSR223 + Groovy for [performances](https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/) with below code using [RandomStringGenerator](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/RandomStringGenerator.html):

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.commons.text.RandomStringGenerator;

JSONObject outerObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
RandomStringGenerator generator = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder().selectFrom("KLMNOPRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray()).build();
RandomStringGenerator generatorGender = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder().selectFrom("MFU".toCharArray()).build();
RandomStringGenerator generatorType = new RandomStringGenerator.Builder().selectFrom("IE".toCharArray()).build();

for(int i = 0;i<=3;i++)
{   
    JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
    innerObject.put("middleName", generator.generate(4));
    innerObject.put("maidenName", generator.generate(4));
    innerObject.put("gender", generatorGender.generate(1));
    innerObject.put("TestingType", generatorType.generate(1));
    jsonArray.put(innerObject);
    outerObject.put("nameList", jsonArray);
}

outerObject.put("Alert", "Testing Alert");
log.info(outerObject.toString());
vars.putObject("jsonData",jsonArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code works perfectly fine. I have accepted your answer as well. Can you please let me know how can I utilize __RandomFromMultipleVars function in Groovy? Is there any function from RandomStringGenerator class which I can use? Please suggest. Thanks once again.

Comment: I was able to achieve it using Arraylist. Once again, appreciate your help.